# Hybris Dashboard Widgets

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I am trying to create a custom dashboard widget on *SAP Hybris* `backoffice`.
I have a `FlexibleSearch` query which returns multiple columns of data, this data will be dynamic and I want to make a dashboard widget which displays these data.

Is that possible ? How I can proceed?

Comment: Please add your code so we can help you. Thanks!

Comment: for creating widgets see  https://help.sap.com/viewer/5c9ea0c629214e42b727bf08800d8dfa/1905/en-US/8bd4366a86691014b818f8dd642790a8.html